# How to add test next to 'secure connection' lock in browser

Tags: security, web, browser

So I just noticed that left of the web address it says 'A Medium Corporation [US]' together with the secure connection lock. How did they do this and can this be done by anyone providing a secure connection?

[image: Medium.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the certificate type you purchase for your website. For this, you need an Extended Validation (EV) certificate.

The difference is that for an EV cert, the certificate authority (the company issuing the certificate for you) needs to verify much closer who you are as a person and as a business. They have to

`- Establish the legal identity as well as the operational and physical presence of website owner.
- Establish that the applicant is the domain name owner or has exclusive control over the domain name.
- Confirm the identity and authority of the individuals acting for the website owner, and that documents pertaining to legal obligations are signed by an authorised officer.`

(Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Issuing_criteria).)

You can get such a certificate starting from around 100 USD / year.

The text near the lock will be a field in the certificate, which will almost always be the company name.